# Complement of a set is a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ - set on the numeric lime such that its complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus{M}$ is a countable set.

Is it true that all points of $M$ are boundary points?

---

I think $M$ colud be a set of irrational numbers or a set of irrational numbers with any number of any elements of the set of rational numbers. For me it looks like all points of $M$ are boundary. BUT my testbook has two answer choise (among otherobviously incorrect):

- All points of $M$ are boundary,
- There are not isolated points in $M$.

The reason why I am asking this question is that both this options are correct, in my opinion, while there is only one correct answer.

Comment: "I think M colud be a set of irrational numbers"  $M$ *could* be that.  But it doesnt have to be that.  For *that* $M$ then $M^c = \mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and so yes, every point of $M$ is a boundary point.  But if $M$ is *not* $\mathbb R\setminus Q$ this doesn't have to be true.

Answer (score 2):

If $M=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$, then $\mathbb R\setminus M$ is countable, but $\frac12(\in M)$, for instance, is *not* a boundary point of $M$.

However, it is true that, if $\mathbb R\setminus M$ is countable, then $M$ has no isolated points.

Comment: wait... is a union of uncountable and countable sets is countable?

Comment: even more: 1/2 is a boundary point of $M$ because there are points that are in $M$ and that are not for all areas like $(1/2-\epsilon;1/2+\epsilon)$

Comment: If e < 1/2 then (1/2-e, 1/2 + e) is a subset of (0,1) and is entirely contained in M and *none* of the points are boundary points.  I think you are confusing *un*countable M with it's countable complement.

Comment: If $K = \mathbb Z$ and $M = \mathbb R \setminus Z$ then $K$ is countable and $M$ is uncountable.  Now *NO* points of $M$ are boundary point of $M$ because for any $x \not \in \mathbb Z$ we can find and $r$ so that $(x-r,x+r)$ contains not integers.  Thus $(x-r,x+r)$ is *completely* within $M$ and *not* a boundary point.

Comment: "because there are points that are in M and that are not for all areas like (1/2−ϵ;1/2+ϵ) "  If $\epsilon = \frac 14$ what points in $(\frac 14, \frac 34)$ are not in M?  M are all real numbers that are not integers.  There are no integers in $(\frac 14, \frac 34)$.

Comment: "wait... is a union of uncountable and countable sets is countable?"  No.  Why do you ask?  $\mathbb Z$ is countable.  $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z = \{$non-integer real numbers$\}$ is uncountable.  The union of countable $\mathbb Z$ with uncountable $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$ is uncountable $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written is confusing but it is $M$ that is *uncountable*.

If we let $K = \mathbb R\setminus M$ be a countable subset.  It should be intuitively clear that.

i) Every $x\in K$ must be a boundary point of $M$.

Because $B_r(x)=(x-r, x+r)$ will have uncountably many points for any $r$.  As $K$ is countable there must be points in $B_r(x)$ that are not in $K$ so $x$ is a boundary point of $K^c = M$.

**This is NOT the statement that was asked about.**

ii) Unless $K$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ not every point of $M$ need be a boundary point of $M$.

If you have any interval $(a,b)\subset M$ then no point $x \in (a,b)$ is a boundary point of $M$.  All we have to do is have $K$ be a countable set where none of the points of $K$ are in $(a,b)$.  That's obviously possible.

Example:  Let $K= \mathbb N$ and $x < 0$.  Or Let $K = \mathbb Z$ and $x = \frac 12$ (As per Jose Carlos Santos *excellent* answer.)

**This IS the statement that was asked about.  And the statement was false.**

iii) $M$ has no isolated points.

If $x\in M$ is an isolated point then there is an $r> 0$ so that $(x-r, x)$ has no points in $M$.  But that means $(x-r,x)\subset K$.  But $K$ is countable and $(x-r, x)$ is uncountable so that is impossible.